# Spring MVC 3.0- The URL mapping is treated as a view when passing a model and view object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and was working on the Hello world application in MVC The URL mapping is searched as a corresponding view when i return the ModelAndView object from the controller..I have included all proper jars.This is the code..
/web-inf/sample-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">             (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd%27%3E)
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs.laks.sample.controller" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> </beans>
```

This is the web.xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">    (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd%27%3E)
   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The HelloWorldController is..

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
    String message = "Hello";
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
   }
}
```

The url was given as //localhost:8080/sample/welcome it gave 404 as it was trying to find welcome.jsp instead of hello.jsp

HTTP Status 404 - /sample/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

---

type Status report

message /sample/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

description The requested resource (/sample/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp) is not available.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `contextConfigLocation` init-param for the dispatcher servlet within your web.xml file. The current configuration is even being read/used by the dispatcher

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Also it looks like you have imported the portlet version of ModelAndView, make sure this is what you desire.  If not import, `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`

Comment: Thanks kevin, I tried but still it is not working.. The same application if i return a string using the model map it is working but if i return the model and view object there seems to be a problem

Comment: @user2006839 does the output of your log change when you specify the init parameter?  I'm referencing the 404 message.

Comment: No the output didnt change.. it still tries to find welcome.jsp and throws 404.

Comment: @Lakshmi the sample-servlet.xml file looks suspiciously light let me compare with my examples.

Comment: I'm assuming your not using portlets since you didn't list a portlet.xml file. But notice that your importing `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView`, I think this should be `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` instead.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Lakshmi, awesome glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong ModelAndView class

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

it should have been

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

everything else is fine.